# Receiver type 'xxx' for instance message is a forward declaration

Tags: ios, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

moving my old application to ARC, I got this error:

```
Receiver type 'Customer_info'  for instance message is a forward declaration
```

Here is my relevant code:

```
[params setValue:[_bill.Customer_info valueForKey:@"date"] forKey:kBillCustomerDate];
```

`_bill` is an object of a model class generated from Core Data.
`Customer_info` is also an object of another model class also generated from Core Data and is a property in `_bill`'s class.

Core Data is imported in the pre compiled header file `app_Prefix.pch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the entity classes, not just the Core Data headers. You description sounds like you're importing one entity but not the `Customer_info` entity.